# Subsetting dataset on dynamic columns

Tags: r

I have a question on data subset based on dynamic column class. For example:

```
#Coming from other source. Dont exaclty know about their names and number of classes. 
#But following are two demography, which will help in imagining the problem
gender <- c(1,2)
agegroup <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
#moredemo.................

# reproducible data
set.seed(1)
col1 <- as.data.frame(rep(gender, 100))
col2 <- as.data.frame(rep(agegroup, 25))
col3 <- runif(200)
datafile <- cbind(col1, col2, col3)
names(datafile)[1] = "gender"
names(datafile)[2] = "agegroup"
datafile <- as.data.frame(datafile)

#Subset is only for gender = 1 and agegroup = 3
#Subset is for every combination of classes in each demography
#No hardcoded name is required, because demography name will not be know
dat_gender_1_agegroup_3 <- datafile[datafile$gender == 1 & datafile$agegroup == 3, ]
```

But there can be more demography and not just gender and agegroup. There can be income or education or race and so on. each of the demography has varying number of class. Kindly help me in getting the subset of the dataset datafile on the varying number of columns. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

Using expand grid for combos then apply to subset:

```
#dummy data
set.seed(123)
mydata <- data.frame(gender = sample(1:2, 100, replace = TRUE),
                     agegroup = sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE))

#groups
gender <- c(1,2)
agegroup <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

#get all combo
myCombo <- expand.grid(gender, agegroup)

#result is a list object
apply(myCombo, 1, function(i){
  mydata[ mydata$gender == i[1] &
            mydata$agegroup == i[2], ]
  })
```

**Edit:** Based on update, I think you just need split command

```
split(datafile, datafile[, 1:2])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But hardcoding gender and agegroup will not serve the purpose. as there can be more than 2 demography and their names may not be know. Thanks

Comment: @skj I think you just need to use `split()`.

Comment: I appreciate the answers. Thank you so much. But I believe I can not save them. I tried, but they are only for the display purpose. Is there any way to save these files, so they can be reused further in the process?

Comment: @skj split returns a list object. You can pass it to lapply to write out into files.

Answer (score 0):

What about (assuming the column names are "gender" and "agegroup"):

```
gender <- c(1,2)
agegroup <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

data_subset <- subset(full_data, gender%in%gender | agegroup%in%agegroup | [AND SO ON])
```

You can add as many [column_name]%in%[values] as you want.

HTH a little!

EDIT: you can very well use & instead of |, obviously.

Comment: Thanks so much for reply. But I need a more generic solution where neither number of demography nor names are known. Data will be subseted for each of the class of demography. For example demo1 = c(1,2), demo2 = c(1,2,3,4), demo = c(6,7,8). Data will be separately subsetted for total combination of 2*4*3 = 24.